I'm not being able to create users in my django application through the registration form that I created
I can create users through the manage.py shell, but not through the registration form, when I click the submit button, it just reloads the page and nothing else happens, also, my vs code is underscoring the create_user function in the line "user = Account.objects.create_user(...", it says "Cannot access attribute "create_user" for class "BaseManager[Account]""
This is my forms.py:
from django import forms from .models import Account

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm): password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'placeholder': 'Enter Password', })) ` confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password', }))


email = forms.EmailField(
    max_length=255, help_text="Required. Add a valid email address.")

document = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'placeholder': '(CPF/RG/PASSPORT)',
}), max_length=15, help_text="Enter a valid CPF, RG, or Passport.")

address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'placeholder': '1337 Example St, FL, US',
}), max_length=255, help_text="Enter your address.")

class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name',
              'username', 'phone_number', 'email', 'address', 'document', 'password']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['phone_number'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = '(xx) x xxxx-xxxx'
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'`

This is my models.py
from django.db import models from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, document, phone_number, email, username, address=None, password=None, TCM_wallet=0):

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('User must have an email address.')
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('User must have a username.')
    if not document:
        raise ValueError('User must provide the document.')
    if not address:
        raise ValueError('User must provide the address.')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        phone_number=phone_number,
        document=document,
        address=address,
        TCM_wallet=TCM_wallet,
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, username, phone_number, document, email, password, address, TCM_wallet=0):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        document=document,
        phone_number=phone_number,
        address=address,
        password=password,
        TCM_wallet=TCM_wallet,
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_active = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superadmin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True) 
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True) 
document = models.CharField( max_length=15, unique=True, help_text='Required. Enter a valid document (CPF, RG, or Passport).') 
address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True) 
TCM_wallet = models.FloatField(default=0, editable=True)

# required fields
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name',
                   'last_name', 'document', 'address', 'phone_number',]

objects = MyAccountManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True`

..and this is my views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect from .forms import RegistrationForm from .models import Account

def register(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)    
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            document = form.cleaned_data['document']
            address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = email.split('@')[0]

            user = Account.objects.create_user(
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                email=email,
                document=document,
                address=address,
                password=password,
                username=username,
            )

            user.phone_number = phone_number
            user.save()
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)

def login(request): return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request): # assuming 'login' is the name of your login url pattern return redirect('login')`

Could someone please help me understanding this one? Thank you..
I expected that the info contained in the user registration form would be collected and saved as user.save().
